# The degree of smooth projective curve included in $\mathbb P^n$ which is nondegenerate is more or equal the dimension of the projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

I had a theorem during lecture, with proof which I don't understand.
Theorem says:

> $ X \subset \mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C})$ smooth projective curve which is
>   nondegenerate (not contained in a hyperplane
>   $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}(\mathbb{C})$) then $\deg(X) \geqslant n $

where $\deg(X)$ for a smooth projective curve $X$ is equal $\deg(i^*H)$ where $i: X \rightarrow  \mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C})$ is inclusion map and $H$ is a hyperplane divisor of $X$

> Proof:
>
> We have proven that $D \in \textrm{Div}(X) \Rightarrow \dim(L(D)) \leqslant
>  deg(D) +1 \Rightarrow dim(|D|) \leqslant \deg(D) $ so let's take the
>   inclusion $i: X \rightarrow  \mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C})$ and $D=i^*H$ .
>   In general $n \leqslant \dim(|D|) \Rightarrow n \leqslant \deg(D)$.

My question is:

**why do we know that "In general $n \leqslant \dim(|D|)$ " ?**

Comment: We have the natural map $H^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(H))\to L(D)$. The curve is non-degenerate implies this map is injective and since the first vector space has dimension $n+1$, it follows that $\dim L(D)\geq n+1$.

Comment: @Mohan what is $O_{\mathbb{P}^n}(H)$? and there is missing bracket somewhere

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(H)$ is the hyperplane line bundle and from which you got $D=i^*H$.